# Inequality Problem on Random Variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose X1, X2,...,Xk are k i.i.d random variables having finite variance. Suppose Xj is another random variable which is independent to all those k random variables and having same distribution as them. Define U=(X1+X2+...+Xk)Xj and V=(X1+X2+...+Xk). Show that the square of correlation coefficient between U and V is less than 1/(k+1)

I actually tried to find out the terms Cov(U,V), Var(U) and Var(V) but then tried to show this inequality but somewhere messed up and could not get the appropriate result.

Comment: Please help somebody

Comment: Show $$\text{Cov(U,V)} = E[X_j]\text{Var}(V)$$ as well as $$\text{Var}(U) = E[X_j^2]\text{Var(V)}$$ then you get as correlation coefficient?

Comment: Is the expression  of Var(U) correct?  If assume this to be correct then also I am not getting the inequality

Comment: Anyone?? please solve

Comment: StackExchange is not a solving machine… what have you tried? What do you get following the hints above? Edit your question with the results you get.